# Batch renaming a single file (always same file name) within a folder to the folder name (100s of folders)

Tags: bash, applescript, batch-rename

I'm currently trying to convert a file that is contained within my Ulysses export (= a bunch of textbundle files). So, once I export all my sheets from my Ulysses (Markdown App), I'll have the following files (slightly over 700 of them) in one folder containing e.g.:

- Exmaple File.textbundle
- Some random name.textbundle Another random
- Another random name.text bundle
- ...

[image: This is what one of these textbundle files looks like]

This is what one of these textbundle files looks like

**Where I need help:**
I'm struggling a bit do create an Automator script, bash or whatever is easier or gets the job done (I can't program) and does the following:

Removes the extension of the textbundle file, so it becomes a folder

[image: Once the extension is removed, the textbundle file becomes a normal folder]

Once the extension is removed, the textbundle file becomes a normal folder

2. Rename the text.md file to the folder name (e.g. Exmaple File.md based on the example from above). ***Keep in mind:** All .md files, no matter what textbundle file is being processed, will **always** have the same - text.md.filename, Not sure why that's the case, but it should make it easier to script, I hope.*
3. Reverse step 1 and add the extension .textbundle back to the folder so it becomes a textbundle file again
4. Move on to the next file e.g. Some random name.textbundle and repeat steps 1-3.

Essentially, I'll have the hundreds of textbundles files and want to have an automaton script that goes through the process (1-3), renaming the text.md contained in each textbundle file so I can cleanly import these into another program.

Anyone know how the code would need to look like?

Comment: Note that `<somename>.textbundle` is already a directory, you don't need to rename it to magically make it one, it only makes a difference in how the Finder app presents it to you.  Anyway... are you saying you have over 700 `*<somename>.textbundle` collections/directories, and from each of those directories you want to grab the `<somename>.textbundle/text.md` file only and rename it to `<somename>.textbundle/<somename>.md`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a folder with content along these lines:

```
$ tree -N
.
|-- name 1.textbundle
|   `-- text.md
|-- name 2.something
|   `-- text.md
|-- name 3.textbundle
|   `-- text.md
|-- name4.textbundle
|   `-- text.md
`-- name5.textbundle
    `-- text.md

5 directories, 5 files
```

Then a script like the following, could be used to rename those `text.md` files within those `*.textbundle` directories, along the lines of how you suggested:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory>" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "$0: '$1' is not a directory" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

find . -type d -name '*.textbundle' | \
while read dirname; do
    base=$(basename "$dirname" .textbundle)
    echo "$dirname => $base:"
    pushd "$dirname" > /dev/null
    if [ -e "text.md" ]; then
        mv "text.md" "$base.md"
        echo "    Moved $dirname/text.md => $dirname/$base.md"
    fi
    popd > /dev/null
done
```

It requires one parameter, the base directory of where you keep all these `*.textbundle` directories. So if that is in `~/Documents/` for instance, you would run it like `<scriptname> ~/Documents`.

Running it from the start the above example directory, it would look like this:

```
$ <script-name> .
./name 1.textbundle => name 1:
    Moved ./name 1.textbundle/text.md => ./name 1.textbundle/name 1.md
./name5.textbundle => name5:
    Moved ./name5.textbundle/text.md => ./name5.textbundle/name5.md
./name 3.textbundle => name 3:
    Moved ./name 3.textbundle/text.md => ./name 3.textbundle/name 3.md
./name4.textbundle => name4:
    Moved ./name4.textbundle/text.md => ./name4.textbundle/name4.md
```

If you run it again, it won't do any accidental damage, it just won't rename any files:

```
$ <script-name> .
./name 1.textbundle => name 1:
./name5.textbundle => name5:
./name 3.textbundle => name 3:
./name4.textbundle => name4:
```

The following script moves all those files back, in case you change your mind:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory>" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "$0: '$1' is not a directory" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

find . -type d -name '*.textbundle' | \
while read dirname; do
    base=$(basename "$dirname" .textbundle)
    echo "$dirname => $base:"
    pushd "$dirname" > /dev/null
    if [ -e "$base.md" ]; then
        mv "$base.md" "text.md"
        echo "    Moved $dirname/$base.md => $dirname/text.md"
    fi
    popd > /dev/null
done
```

It too takes the base directory as the (only) parameter.

```
$ <revert-script-name> .
./name 1.textbundle => name 1:
    Moved ./name 1.textbundle/name 1.md => ./name 1.textbundle/text.md
./name5.textbundle => name5:
    Moved ./name5.textbundle/name5.md => ./name5.textbundle/text.md
./name 3.textbundle => name 3:
    Moved ./name 3.textbundle/name 3.md => ./name 3.textbundle/text.md
./name4.textbundle => name4:
    Moved ./name4.textbundle/name4.md => ./name4.textbundle/text.md
```

And it too will skip the renaming if it doesn't find an appropriate `*.md` file.

Both scripts use `find` to find directory names of the required name pattern, and then visit each one of them and look for an appropriate `*.md` file, renaming it when found. `basename` is used to take the directory name and simplify it the last part of the path, minus the `.textbundle` extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to use the script, but it's not working for me. I'm guessing I'm missing something. I copied your script from above into a text editor and made sure it has a .sh extension. I then tried " md-renamer.sh ~/Downloads/Ulysses_Export" but got: "zsh: command not found: md-renamer.sh"

Comment: Be sure to also mark it as executable: `chmod a+x md-renamer.sh`

Comment: (oh, and if don't have the current directory in your `$PATH`, you will need to address it as `./md-renamer.sh`)

Comment: Wow, nice! And thanks so much! Now it works. I feel so powerful - even though you coded it : ) I changed the #!/bin/bash part to #!/bin/zsh. Not sure what that means, but my terminal always has zsh. I will forever be in your debt.

Comment: I think the `bash` vs `zsh` doesn't matter for my fairly agnostic bit of scripting above, but generally speaking you should _not_ do that. There are significant differences between the two scripting languages. :)